# Why am I getting the error: OperationalError at /table/ no such table: table_book

Tags: python, django

Whenever I run the program, I get the following error:

```
OperationalError at /table/ 
no such table: table_book
```

It says that there's an error on line 7 in my template file.

Here is my template.html:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>author</th>
  <th>title</th>
  <th>publication year</th>
</tr>
{% for b in obj %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ b.author }}</td>
  <td>{{ b.title }}</td>
  <td>{{ b.publication_year }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Here is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def display(request):
    return render(request, 'template.tmpl', {'obj': models.Book.objects.all()})
```

Here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    publication_year = models.IntegerField()
```

Here is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # /table/
    url(r'^$', views.display, name='display'),
]
```

Can somebody please tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database table table_book is missing. Did you run makemigrations and migrate ?

Comment: Oh I forgot about migrations... I will go do this now.